# Finding out eigen values and vectors of huge sparse matrices in python is horribly slower than Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I am trying to find 100 eigen values and vectors of a huge sparse matrix of size 409600x409600. I am using `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` for this and it's taking ages to find the result whereas `eigs` on matlab solves it within 10 mins.Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Python:

`eigenvectors, eigenvalues = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(Laplacian, k=100, which='SM')`

Matlab:

`eigCnt = 100;`
`[eigenvectors, eigenvalues] = eigs(Laplacian, eigCnt, 'SM');`

where `Laplacian` is a sparse matrix of size `409600x409600` with `10418204` non zero entries
    `

Comment: Show us your matlab code solving the problem, also attached the format of the matrix

Comment: MATLAB has a lot of corporate dollars to throw at this sort of calculation.  But you can read the sparse `eigs` docs as well as we can.

Comment: @Adam I've updated it

Comment: @hpaulj I am looking to do it in Python. Hence the question :)

Comment: We get a lot of questions here about MATLAB being faster than Python. The one is an expensive software package, the other is free. You have to pick: cheap or fast?